# Assistance on setup to Connect an offsite server to the LAN via RRAS VPN - Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn, rras

I have an office LAN protected using a Zyxel Zywall USG 300. I've set up an L2TP/ipsec VPN on that which accepts connections using a shared secret and I've tested this from multiple clients.

I have a server offsite and want to set up RRAS to use a persistent connection to the VPN so that it can carry out network jobs even with no one logged in (I'm using it for Micorosft DPM secondary backup).

If I create a vpn as if I were setting up a users laptop it can dial in no problem but if I set up a demand dial interface in RRAS it errors.

- I enable RRAS ticking only demand dial interface (branch office routing)
- Select network interfaces, right click and choose new demand dial interface
- Name the VPN ToCompany
- Select connect using VPN
- And then L2TP as the vpn type
- enter the IP address (double-checked for typos!)
- select Route IP packets on this interface
- specify static route to remote network as 10.0.0.0/24 with metric of 1
- add dial out credentials (again double checked for typos and confirmed with other vpn connections
- click finish
- now I right-click on the new interface and choose properties and then the security tab
- I change Data encryption to optional
- select only PAP for Authentication (both as per manufacturer of Zywall)
- click advanced settings against type of vpn and set shared secret
- then I select the new interface, right-click and choose connect

this dials and then errors with either 720 or 811 as the error codes. However, if I create a VPN by going to Network & Sharing center and setting up as if I was creating a VPN from my laptop to the office (say) it dials successfully

so I know the VPN settings are correct *and* the machine can connect to the VPN.

Suggests very strongly the problem is how I'm setting up RRAS. Can anyone help?

Comment: On the USG the log item: 
"info
IKE
[COOKIE] Invalid cookie, no sa found
se.rv.er.ip:500
fi.re.wa.ll:500
IKE_LOG" ties up with the error from RRAS

Answer (score 1):

> "On the USG the log item: "info IKE [COOKIE] Invalid cookie, no sa found se.rv.er.ip:500 fi.re.wa.ll:500 IKE_LOG" ties up with the error from RRAS"

You're failing on phase 1(IKE).

1. "No SA found" normally points to a firewall issue. Is port 500 open on the RRAS server?
2. "Invalid Cookie" could also mean a setting mismatch. Make sure your SA renegotiation time is the same on both ends.

Comment: I can connect to the VPN via the Network & Sharing Center but the same settings in RRAS fail...

Comment: Hmm, It has to be a conflicting setting somewhere...